# Working with more than one class

Tags: java

I am new to java learning java from home using udacity.com and they fave given a question which i am stuck and cant get it working.

project is just to check if player move is not out of bound in chess game and then to see if Queen's move is valid or not. we have to see these 3 thing should work.

1. In the Queen class, override the `isValidMove` method
2. First call the parent's `isValidMove` to check for the boundaries.
3. Add more code to check for the Queen's specific move validity.

I have Main class, Game class, Position class, Piece class(Parent class) Queen class(child).
I got 1 and 3 working but can't understand how to get 2nd working it gives me error if i try calling `Piece.isValidMove` in main before `Queen.isValidMove`.

my codes as follows

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Piece piece = new Piece();
        Queen queen = new Queen();
        Position testPosition = new Position(3,7);
        if(queen.isValidMove(testPosition)){
            System.out.println("Yes, I can move there.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Nope, can't do!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Game.java**

```
public class Game {
    Piece [][] board;
    // Constructor creates an empty board
    Game(){
        board = new Piece[8][8];
    }
}
```

**Position.java**

```
public class Position {
    int row;
    int column;
    // Constructor using row and column values
    Position(int r, int c){
        this.row = r;
        this.column = c;
    }
}
```

**Piece.java**

```
public class Piece {
    Position position;

    boolean isValidMove(Position newPosition){
        if(position.row>0 && position.column>0
                && position.row<8 && position.column<8){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Queen.java**

```
public class Queen extends Piece {
    int row;
    int column;
    boolean isValidMove(Position newPosition){
        if(newPosition.column == this.column || newPosition.row == this.row|| Math.abs(newPosition.column - this.column) == Math.abs(newPosition.row - this.row)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you are getting exactly?

Comment: I think its `super.isValidMove()` .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ (preferably 10 lines or less) to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

> but can't understand how to get 2nd working it gives me error if i try calling Piece.isValidMove in main before Queen.isValidMove

The task says you need to call the parent's `isValidMove` in `Queen.isValidMove`, not in `Main`. And the syntax you need is `super.isValidMove`. So in `Queen.java`, do

```
boolean isValidMove(Position newPosition){
    // combine super.isValidMove(newPosition) and your current code
}
```

You don't need to change `Main`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Piece.isValidMove(Piece.java:5)
 at Queen.isValidMove(Queen.java:5)
 at Main.main(Main.java:5) this is what i get after using the super in queen class

Comment: `public class Queen extends Piece {
    int row;
    int column;
    boolean isValidMove(Position newPosition){
        if(!super.isValidMove(position)){
            return false;
        }
        if(newPosition.column == this.column || newPosition.row == this.row|| Math.abs(newPosition.column - this.column) == Math.abs(newPosition.row - this.row)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: sorry for the mess i cant seem to get the code in the code look format

Comment: 1. `Piece.isValidMove` is implemented wrong; 2. There is a similar error in this method; 3. You shouldn't have `row` and `column` fields in `Queen`, it already has `position` from `Piece`.

Comment: I think that's enough hints.

Comment: it gives cannot resolve symbol column, and same for row if i remove it